# faint underlines show up under my social media icons

Tags: html, icons, css

I used this code and plugged in my correct info, and it worked to put my social media icons horizontal on my website, however, there are faint black lines under each icon, and I know that is not part of their design. Any ideas how to fix? Thanks!

```
<div id="social_icons">
<a href="http://example.com"><img src="http://example.com/yourimage1.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://example.com"><img src="http://example.com/yourimage2.jpg"></a>
</div>

<style>
#social_icons img, a { display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the default `text-decoration: underline` from your `a` tags:

```
<style>
  #social_icons img, a { display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default `text-decoration: underline` from  a tags

it should be

```
<style>
  #social_icons img, 
  #social_icons a {
  display: inline-block; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  }
</style>
```

or override the default a tags with `!important` which generally i dont prefer

for example

```
#social_icons a {
  text-decoration: none!important; 
  }
```